# Query intersection with activerecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'd really like to do the following query with the help with active record

```sql
(select *
from people p join cities c join services s
where p.city_id = c.id and p.id = s.person_id and s.type = 1)

intersect

(select *
from people p join cities c join services s
where p.city_id = c.id and p.id = s.person_id and s.type = 2)
```

Problem is, first of all, mysql doesn't support intersect. However, that can be worked around of. The thing is that I can get active record to output anything even close to that.

In active record the best I could do was to issue multiple queries then use `reduce :&`  to join them, but then I get an Array, not a Relation. That's a problem for me because I want to call things like limit, etc. Plus, I think it would be better to the intersection to be done by the database, rather than ruby code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is probably solvable without intersection, something like:

```
Person.joins(:services).where(services: {service_type: [1,2]}).group(
   people: :id).having('COUNT("people"."id")=2')
```

However the following is a general approach I use for constructing intersection like queries in ActiveRecord:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person

  def self.with_types(*types)
    where(service_type: types)
  end
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
  has_many :people, inverse_of: :city
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city, inverse_of: :people

  def self.with_cities(cities)
    where(city_id: cities)
  end

  def self.with_all_service_types(*types)
    types.map { |t|
      joins(:services).merge(Service.with_types t).select(:id)
    }.reduce(scoped) { |scope, subquery|
      scope.where(id: subquery)
    }
  end
end

Person.with_all_service_types(1, 2)
Person.with_all_service_types(1, 2).with_cities(City.where(name: 'Gold Coast'))
```

It will generate SQL of the form:

```
SELECT "people".*
  FROM "people"
 WHERE "people"."id" in (SELECT "people"."id" FROM ...)
   AND "people"."id" in (SELECT ...)
   AND ...
```

You can create as many subqueries as required with the above approach based on any conditions/joins etc so long as each subquery returns the id of a matching person in its result set.

Each subquery result set will be AND'ed together thus restricting the matching set to the intersection of all of the subqueries.

*UPDATE*

For those using AR4 where `scoped` was removed, my other answer provides a semantically equivalent `scoped` polyfil which `all` is not an equivalent replacement for despite what the AR documentation suggests. Answer here: [With Rails 4, Model.scoped is deprecated but Model.all can't replace it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198963/with-rails-4-model-scoped-is-deprecated-but-model-all-cant-replace-it/18327912#18327912)

Comment: Note that the `scoped` ActiveRecord class method (as used in `reduced(scoped)`) was removed in Rails 4.1, but the original solution works by substituting `all`.

Comment: Note that the first method may return service with service type `[1, 3]` too.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue, and found only one solution: multiple joins against the same association.  This may not be too rails-ish since I'm constructing the SQL string for the joins, but I haven't found another way. This will work for an arbitrary number of service types (cities doesn't seem to factor in, so that join was omitted for clarity):

```
s = [1,2]
j = ''
s.each_index {|i|
  j += " INNER JOIN services s#{i} ON s.person_id = people.id AND s#{i}.type_id = #{s[i]}" 
}
People.all.joins(j)
```

Comment: NOTE: this is definitely going to bog down if your service list becomes large.

Comment: This is a sql injection attack waiting to happen